# Upload Image iOS to PHP

Tags: php, ios

I am currently trying to upload an image from my iOS application to a php backend.  I have followed the samples online; however, I am receiving a PHP error code of 3 (UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL).  Can anyone help me out?  I'm using [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler].

I have read some people disable the Connection header, but that isn't working either.  Is there something server side I should check?

```
<?
$uploaddir = '';      //Uploading to same directory as PHP file
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file;

if ($_FILES['userfile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

} else {
    die("Upload failed with error code " . $_FILES['userfile']['error']);
}
?>
```

Comment: See my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15965682/how-to-upload-image-to-server-using-json/15965845#15965845)

Answer (score 0):

you can upload/send any data on php by using POST/GET method of iOS.

for post method

[HTTP Post method php and ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16057660/http-post-method-php-and-ios/16057759#16057759)

For Get method

http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example/

For both

[How to send POST and GET request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673127/iphone-sdk-xcode-4-2-ios-5-how-do-i-send-a-json-to-url-post-and-get-resolv)